# how to understand angles expressed in rms degree

Tags: angle

recently i was going through a system which can detect laser threats arround 360 degree field of view, but the specification says the angle accuracy in rms

how to understand this kind of angles,what actually rms means here ?

please find the datasheet [here](http://www.aselsan.com.tr/en-us/capabilities/electro-optic-systems/air-platforms/lias-laser-warning-receiver-system)

Answer (score 1):

RMS = ROOT MEAN SQUARE

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square

You use the r.m.s. error as a measure of the spread of the measured values about the predicted y value (in this case your angles).